# OpenMP For-Loops yield different Results with and without Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I am new to multithreading and I found the following issue while trying to parallelize some for-loops, in which I manipulate 3D Arrays.
When I run the code using only a single thread, I get the value of `E_total` I would expect. However when I use the same code with *multiple threads* and OpenMP, where I set `#pragma omp parallel for` in the following way

```
    // DO FIRST COMPUTATION STEP ON 3D ARRAY
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < N; ix++) {
        for (size_t iy = 0; iy < N; iy++) {
            for (size_t iz = 0; iz < N; iz++) {
                A1[ix][iy][iz] = ...;
            }
        }
    }

    // DO SECOND COMPUTATION --AFTER-- FIRST COMPUTATION
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < N; ix++) {
        for (size_t iy = 0; iy < N; iy++) {
            for (size_t iz = 0; iz < N; iz++) {
                A2[ix][iy][iz] = ...;
                E_pot += something * A1[ix][iy][iz];
                E_int += something * A2[ix][iy][iz];
            }
        }
    }
    E_total += (E_pot + E_int);    // This result changes when 'omp parallel for' is used
```

I see that I get a **different result for** `E_total`.
Since the looped operations are either additive or grid-point specific (independent between different `ijk`), they should not depend on any ordering inside the loop.

Is it possible that the second for-loop is started before all of the previous first-loop-operations have been finished? If so, how could I prevent that or what other mistakes would I need to watch out for?

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I could not find related problems online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have a race condition on the two variables `E_pot` and `E_int`.  Please add a `reduction(+:E_pot)` and `reduction(+:E_int)` to the second `parallel for` construct.

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked perfectly! Do you want to repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this code is that there is a race condition between the different threads.  The `E_pot` and `E_int` variables are shared between the worker threads and thus the threads are destroying each other's value from time to time.

To fix this, please apply the `reduction` clause (see [Reduction Clauses and Directives](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu117.html#x152-1720002.21.5) in the OpenMP API specification):

```
// DO SECOND COMPUTATION --AFTER-- FIRST COMPUTATION
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:E_pot) reduction(+:E_int)
for (size_t ix = 0; ix < N; ix++) {
    for (size_t iy = 0; iy < N; iy++) {
        for (size_t iz = 0; iz < N; iz++) {
            A2[ix][iy][iz] = ...;
            E_pot += something * A1[ix][iy][iz];
            E_int += something * A2[ix][iy][iz];
        }
    }
}
```

There some more changes that you could look into and see if they help:

Depending on the value of `N` it might be worth adding a `collapse(2)` clause (see [Worksharing-Loop Construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu48.html#x73-730002.11.4)) to the `parallel for` directive to merge the two outer loops into a single loop that then runs for `N*N` iterations.  For small `N`, the  thread then can work better, as more iterations can be distributed across the worker threads.

If you add `schedule(static)` explicitly (it's the default for most OpenMP implementations when you don't say anything, but it's technically not guaranteed), then you can add `nowait` to the first loop.  With that there's no implicit barrier at the end of the first parallel loop and threads that have completed their chunk of work there can proceed to the second loop.  The `schedule(static)` is needed, because then both the first and second loop have the same parallelization and that trick then works.  Note: if you added `collapse(2)` for the first loop, then the second loop also needs to have the `collapse(2)` so that the parallelization is the same.

Comment: Just to add: In this case, declare E_pot and E_int as atomic variable would also solve this problem, (which is a standard C++ way). And it may also get better performance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your statement about performance is not true.  `E_pot` and `E_int` are highly contended variables which are continuously modified by the worker threads.  The code would effectively run close to serialized.  Don't use atomic variables in such cases.  This is a standard reduction pattern and it will likely always give better performance than atomic variables.

Comment: Here's the math: with `E_pot` and `E_int` being atomic variables, you get 2*N^3 atomic accesses that all conflict with each other, therefore trigger the cache coherence protocol. With the `reduction` clause, you'll get 2*N^3 local (!) cache accesses and the compiler will likely even keep the two variables in registers (so no memory access at all). Then for the reduction you'll get on the order of 2*log(t) (t: number of threads) or maybe 2*t atomic updates.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not familiar to OpenMP, and I was just thinking about something like a lock or scope guard. The optimization about thread local cache is awesome!

Comment: Thank you! This was very insightful. 
I also tried around with the collapse() function, but I wasn't aware of the need to add it to the second loop as well.

Comment: You can freely use `collapse()` for either of the loops.  Only when you want to elide the implicit barrier of the first loop, then you have to make sure that the loops are statically scheduled and that the way the second loop is parallelized exactly matches the parallelization of the first loop.  That would include things like `schedule()` and `collapse` clauses.